# Enhancing the Database Design

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My CMS Application which lets users to post Classifieds, Articles, Events, Directories, Properties etc has its database designed as follows :

## 1st Approach:

Each Section (i.e 'classifieds','events' etc) has three tables dedicated to store data relevant to it:

**Classified:**

1. classified-post
2. classified-category
3. classified-post-category

**Event:**

1. events_post.
2. events_category.
3. events_post-category.

The same applies for `Articles, Properties, Directories` etc. each Section has three tables dedicated to its posts, categories.
The problem with this approach is:

- Too many database table. (which leads to increasing number of model,
  controller files)
- Two Foreign Key's to avoid duplicate entries in associative tables. 
  For example:
   Lets say table `comments, ratings, images` belongs to `classified-post`, `events-posts` etc, so the structure of the tables would be: 
  **Image** `[id, post_id, section]`
  The second FK **section** must be stored and associated to avoid duplicate posts.

## 2nd Approach:

This approach will have single posts table which has **section** column associated to each posts as foreign key. i.e

**post**: `id, section, title etc` ....`VALUES ( 1, 'classifieds','abc') (2,'events','asd')` 
While the second approach is little bit cumbersome when doing sql queries, it eases up the process when performing relational table queries. ex: table images, ratings, comments belongs to posts table.
**image** `[ id, post_id (FK) ]`
While this approach seems clean and easy, this will end up in having oodles of columns in posts table, that it will have columns related to events, classifieds, directories etc which will lead to performance issues while querying for rows and columns.
The same applies for categories. It could be either one of the two approach, either save **section** column as second foreign key or have separate tables for each sections ( 1st approach ).

So now my question is, which approach is considered to be better than the other? does any of the two approaches have benefit over the other in performance wise? or what is the best approach to tackle while dealing with these paradigms?

Comment: I admire the courage for those who attempt an answer...My 2 cents: If you have the resources, go with option 1. It is more flexible and will be easier to extend. However, it will take longer to produce. Consider future change of requirements before you adopt generalization.

Comment: @Mohsen, I'm Just curious why you had to edit the table name from classifieds_posts to classified-post and categories to category! Just curious ..

Comment: [Schema naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions) standardized on non plural table names.

Comment: I respect Microsoft's naming convention for SQL server databases. but since a comments or users table which stores multiple comments or users, naming it comments, users rather than (singular) comment, user sounds more logical. and since I'm working on a Php based framework for my current project which strictly follows plural names for database table, it's better for me to stick around to it.

Comment: Naming is totally opinion based, but think about this: a row in COMMENTS table is itself a comment , just like an employee in EMP table. in this view Tables are treated by themselves not by their relations. It seems Database Design is more abstract concept than Microsoft or PHP

Answer (score 2):

I will favor *second approach* with some considerations.
A standard database design guidance is that the designer should first create a [fully normalized dsign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms) then selective [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) can be performed for performance reasons.
**Normalization** is the process of organizing the fields and tables of a relational database to minimize ***redundancy*** and ***dependency***.
**Denormalization** is the process of attempting to optimize the read ***performance*** of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data.

**Hint:** *Programmers building their first database are often primarily concerned with performance. There’s no question that performance is important. A bad design can easily result in database operations that take ten to a hundred times as much time as they should.*

 A very likely example could be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database/8113064#8113064)

A draft model following the mentioned approach could be:
 [image: draft cms model]

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 has the problem of too many tables

Approach 2 has too many columns

Consider storing your data on a single table like Approach 2, but dividing storing all the optional foreign key data in XML.

The XML field will only have data that it needs for a particular section. If a new section is added, then you just add that kind of data to the XML

Your table may look like

```
UserID  int FK
ImageID int FK
ArtifactCategory int FK
PostID int FK
ClassifiedID int FK
...
Other shared
...
Secondary xml
```

Now you have neither too many columns nor too many tables