# Modeling Upvotes / Likes - one table per type, or one big table?

Tags: database-design, schema, normalization

I'm modeling a system that will have "upvotes" across various entity types - `Reports`, `Reviews`, and `Collections`.

These are the only three entities that can be upvoted, though there may be more in the future.

Currently, the db schema has `ReportUpvotes`, `ReviewUpvotes`, and `CollectionUpvotes`.

I'm wondering if it would be better to bring all of these tables together into a single `Upvotes` table, with an enum for `Type`.

What should I be considering when evaluating this kind of decision?

Comment: You may also be interested in: [Implementing comments and Likes in database](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/533120).

Comment: [Data Model of SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) maybe a good reference for your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The idea of storing entities of the same type (Upvotes) in one table makes perfect sense to me. However, it may be implemented in different ways. Right of the bat I can tell about 3 ways.

The first one that is proposed in the question (unless I misunderstood it) results in polymorphic association, a practice generally considered as bad. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that you want to have something like `CREATE TABLE Upvotes (..., type enum ('Report','Review',...), entity_id int)` where `entity_id` refers to one of the `Report`,`Review`, etc tables based on value of `type` column. There is no way you can enforce such constraint without triggers.

Second is exclusive arcs. A bit better approach (referential integrity can be enforced), but still quite ugly. If you go this way, you will have something like

```
CREATE TABLE Upvotes(..., report_id INT , review_id INT, ...., 
CONSTRAINT FK_REPORT FOREIGN KEY (report_id) REFERENCES Report(report_id), 
CONSTRAINT FK_REPORT FOREIGN KEY (review_id) REFERENCES Review(review_id)
);
```

First of all you need to ensure that only one of (report_id,review_id, etc) is not null for any row. Secondly, adding new entity type that can be upvoted means adding new column to `Upvotes`.

The third way is a "common parent" approach.  You are creating a new table, say `UpvotableEntity` (bad name, just for illustration). Then make it parent table  for existing  ReportUpvotes, ReviewUpvotes, and CollectionUpvotes. Finally, `Upvotes` table stores `upvotable_entity_id`.

Comment: Yeah, the first approach is what I was considering - a single "EntityId" field that gets used to query against whatever table corresponds to the ENUM.  The common parent approach - would you mind explaining this a bit further, or even a link that demos the concept would be helpful.

Comment: Also, I want to add that from practicability perspective having everything normalized and enforced should not be the goal by itself; consider time and complexity of each solution.

Comment: Fantastic, I just ordered that book.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Wouldn't the common parent approach (child.Parentid) limit the relationship between child and parent to be one-to-one instead of one-to-many?  Or, am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 5):

Just like in software development, requirements should strongly influence what you should do.

Do you need to be able to display all upvotes/likes together or in one place?

Do you envisage adding many more types of upvotes?

Answering yes to either of these two would make me lean towards a single table.

Apart from this, just like in software development, if tables are very similar in structure and purpose, they can be "refactored" into a single table. For this reason also, I would lean towards having a single table.