# MySQL Database Design with tags across multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am working on some web apps which should all use the same user table. The different applications all need different table designs, so I created one table for each app, with the UserID being a foreign key referring to the user table.

Now I want to add tags to all apps. The tags should be in one table for every app in order to easily query all tags from one user(for searching purposes, the search should be able to find everything tagged with that tag, no matter the app). Personally, I don't think splitting them up into multiple tables would be a good idea, but I am not that into database design so I might be wrong. My current attempt looks something like this:

[tags]

```
EntryID | UserID | Tag
```

The thing is that the EntryIDs of course would have to be unique across all app tables with this solution. For the notes app I need something like this:

[notes]

```
EntryID | UserID | title | content | etc.
```

For my calendar I have the following table:

[calendar]

```
EntryID | UserID | name | start | end | etc.
```

Now I don't know how to manage those EntryIDs. Should I create another table like this

[entries]

```
EntryID | UserID | type
```

with type being something like "note" or "calendar", and EntryID being the primary key? And should the type be something like an integer, or a string, or is there a possibility to kind of refer to another table in the type column? And should I then make the EntryIDs in the app tables into foreign keys referring to the entries table?

I put the userID in every table because I think this is going to speed up querying, for example when I need every tag one user has set across all apps. I know normalization usually prohibits this, but I again think that it would very much increase query speed and reduce load for both the MySQL server and my back-end.

I would appreciate every tip for structuring this, and thanks in advance!

Comment: it is not really clear to me what you are asking or what the overall intent of your data model is.  For example, what is a tag in your system?  How does a tag relate to a note or a calendar?  Also what is expected data access pattern (i.e. how and when are various reads and writes on these tables made)?  As it stands right now, it is really unclear what an appropriate schema may be.

Comment: The users should be able to add a tags to a date in the calendar, like "important" or "work", and the same goes for notes. They then can search for "work" and find everything that is related to their work, or for "important" and find everything marked as important. Of course writing to the tables occurs when the users change stuff in the apps, reads would either select like the dates of the next two weeks or the notes of the last two, or they would occur when the user searches for a tag, and then it would have to show results from  both the notes and the calendar.

Comment: Seems like you are on the right track. Put the `type` from `entries` into `tags`. You will need another table with the list of valid `type` values. Ensure you maintain RI between tables, perhaps with cascading deletes, so if a `calendar` row is deleted, the tags go too. Your main problem is that when you search and find all the "important" tags for user "fred", you then have to fetch the data from different tables depending upon the `type`, then put it together somehow. Which could get a bit messy.

Comment: To answer the specific bit about foreign keys, it is generally done with an int column, with arbitrary values. So 1 = "Important", but your code should be agnostic about that (don't hardcode `1` - the user selects "Important" from a picklist in the UI, which is populated from  a reference table, which is then looked up to get the value `1` which is then used to search `tags`.)  Putting `UserID` in each table is OK (this is de-normalization for performance) provided you take care to maintain the RI and keep the data clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance, similar to this:

[image]

I'm not sure what the role of the user is supposed to be here, exactly. In the model above, user "owns" an entry and (presumably) tags it. If you want multiple users to (be able to) tag the same entry, USER would need to be connected to the junctions table TAG_ENTITY.

For more on how to physically implement inheritance, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12037398/533120).

You may also be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317463/533120) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8113064/533120).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and especially for the links. I have implemented this scheme in my database, now I only need to finish my backend :-) Just one more question: What program do you use to make these schemes? Just curious, right now I'm making these by hand which is okay but does not look nearly as nifty.

Comment: @Benedikt Visio 2007.