# How to add comment model in flask

Tags: python, flask, model, flask-sqlalchemy

users model

```
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = "users"
  id = db.Column('user_id',db.Integer , primary_key=True)
  username = db.Column('username', db.String(20), unique=True , index=True)
  password = db.Column('password' , db.String(250))
  posts = db.relationship('Post', backref = 'user', lazy = 'dynamic')

  def __init__(self , username ,password ):
    self.username = username
    self.password = password
```

posts model

```
class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(140))
    text = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    def __init__(self, title, text):
        self.title = title
        self.text = text
```

now I want to add comments model but dont know how to do it .please help me in comments view also .
comments should be connected to user and post .

Thank You

Comment: if you dont want to answer no problem but please dont down vote it .let someone else answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database

Comment: https://www.google.com.np/search?q=how+is+coment+table+designed+along+with+user+and+post+table&oq=how+is+coment+table+designed+along+with+user+and+post+table&aqs=chrome..69i57.20678j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Hope you have some ideas from these links. Good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself 
here is the comments model

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

    text = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('posts.post_id'))
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
```