# Efficient way for storing the feedbacks of a website in database

Tags: sql, database, database-design, mariadb

I am designing the database to store the feedback given by the users. I am using mariaDB. I am just wondering if my database design is efficient. Also, Can I improve it?

We can have the following tables to store the feedback data:-

- Feedback - Table to store feature id and option no with feedback ID
  as Primary key.
- Features - Feature corresponding to feature ID.
- Options - Options corresponding to option no.
- User details- Browser details corresponding to the feedback and user
  ID.
- Users- User info corresponding to User ID.

[image: ER diagram]

I have taken reference from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database) question.

Comment: *"I am just wondering if my database design is efficient. Also, Can I improve it?"* Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: To judge the usefulness of a schema, one needs to provide the queries that will be applied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use a table for store browser details, you can store it in the feedback table ?
I think it's more relevant

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other thing I should do to make it efficient?

Comment: Well i don't see any things else to change. 
Maybe you can tell us more about your feedback feature, like the use cases and we can see if we can improve more

Comment: This should have been a comment as it does not attempt to answer the question in anny way..

Comment: Also browser details what are those user_agent stuff and things like that? @shivank01 then it would be more efficient to make a separated table where you store unique browser details and use a browser_detail_id in your table to link as it would conserve disk space and int's are faster to insert/update.. As most users would most likely use the same browsers with the same user_agents...