# Column naming convention that act as PK and FK (Subtype relationship)

Tags: mysql, database, entity-relationship

I use MySQL.

In all my tables, I use the naming convention of the primary key as 'id' and foreign key as 'entity_id'. For example:

```
Animal
---------
id (PK)
hospital_id(FK)
```

Now I am implementing the "category" Entity-relationship so I will have the tables of Cat, Dog which is the sub-type of Animal table. So what naming should I use for that single column that is both a PK and FK.

Below is the naming I can think of, suggest if any of this is correct. I want the name of the column as explicit as possible so that anyone looking at the database can know it's a category relationship as fast as possible.

### Naming 1:

```
Animal
---------
id (PK)

Cat
---------
id (PK,FK)

Dogs
---------
id (PK,FK)
```

Naming style - Follow primary key convention.

pros - Nothing to change.

cons - Doesn't depict the category relationship.

### Naming 2:

```
Animal
---------
id (PK)

Cat
---------
animal_id (PK,FK)

Dogs
---------
animal_id (PK,FK)
```

Naming style - Follow foreign key convention.

pros - Easy to know it's a foreign key.

cons - Not sure if it's correct.

### Naming 3:

```
Animal
---------
animal_id (PK)

Cat
---------
animal_id (PK,FK)

Dogs
---------
animal_id (PK,FK)
```

Naming style - Not sure.

pros - Can identify the relationship at first glance.

cons - break my primary key convention.

I refer the design from 
the accepted solution in [Implementing Comments and Likes in database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112831/implementing-comments-and-likes-in-database) if it helps.

Comment: I prefer 3, but this is entirely opinion based

Comment: So there is no convention on this? I see, thank you.

Comment: Nope, but its useful to set site standards